# Создание проекта в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Не могу понять почему при создании проекта в PyCharm появляется такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй убрать пробелы из пути в проект.

Comment: попробовал, всё такая же ошибка

Comment: Попробуй переустанови PyCharm и при выборе установки выбери .PATH

(Могу ошибаться, но она по-моему там есть)

Comment: ошибка была в правах доступа........... не знал что я так затупить могу)